# How can I sync files when I plug in my USB

Tags: 10.10, usb, sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep a folder synchronized to an external USB hard drive in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474/how-can-i-keep-a-folder-synchronized-to-an-external-usb-hard-drive-in-ubuntu)

I was thinking it would be EXTREMELY useful if I could sync the files between a folder on my USB and a folder on my desktop.

If someone can give me a simple set of instructions on this topic I would be thrilled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps I think I created a duplicate post of this topic found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474/how-can-i-keep-a-folder-synchronized-to-an-external-usb-hard-drive-in-ubuntu).