# Running a script when connecting a USB device

Tags: usb

I am trying to run a script whenever a pendrive is connected to my system.
I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284224/autorun-a-script-after-i-plugged-or-unplugged-a-usb-device) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-502864.html) question and it is working, but there are still some problems.

This is my `udev` rules file:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="8564", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000", RUN+="/usr/local/my_script.sh"
```

And this is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

env > /tmp/env.out
cp -r /media/*device-name*/* ~/test/
```

I have two questions:

1. Whenever I plug my USB device in, the script is executed because a file `env.out` is generated in `/tmp`, but **the data from the USB device are not copied to the test directory**.

   If I run the script manually, it works fine! Why?
2. How can I make my rules file more general so that it will work for any USB device which is connected without knowing its ID?

My idea behind this is to copy all the data from any connected USB device to my computer automatically when it is connected.

Comment: aren't you just trying to do this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/474/how-can-i-keep-a-folder-synchronized-to-an-external-usb-hard-drive

Comment: @virtualxtc Thanks for this suggestion! But I want to know What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: can you please tell me what is wrong with my script? Why is it not working?

Comment: Also, just a heads up - I've learned the hard way that specific questions like this usually are better suited for superuser than askubuntu.

Comment: If this would have been the problem of permissions then it would have showed up when I tried to run it manually, isn't it?

Comment: A guess, but '~' expansion might not work in this case (I'm not sure which user the script runs under but it might be one that doesn't have a home directory). Try it with an absolute path.

Comment: I was thinking that the udev user/group doesn't have the correct permissions, but I really have no idea.

Comment: @chronitis I tried giving absolute path but still, No luck! :(

Comment: Also: the udev rule occurs when the block device (`/dev/sdb1` or whatever) is created. I don't think it will have been mounted at this point (ie, `/media/*device name*` is probably either empty or doesn't exist). You probably need to explicitly mount it first, or somehow wait until `udisks` or similar has mounted it for you. I'm afraid I'm not certain how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer my own question:

**1. The script was not running because it needed `sudo` rights to run.**

To solve this, make this script `sudo` executable:

- Edit the `sudoers` file using:

  ```
  sudo visudo
  ```
- After line 25 (i.e `%sudo ALL=(ALL)`) add this:

  ```
  username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/username/my_script.sh
  ```

Now we can use `sudo` in this script without being asked for the `sudo` password. However, this may cause *some security problems*, so please refer to this question: [How do I sudo a command in a script without being asked for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password)

**2. Answer to my second question:**

To make this script **work for any USB device** which is connected, change the `udev` rules file's content to this:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="`****`", ATTRS{idProduct}=="`****`", RUN+="/usr/local/my_script.sh"
```

The asterik (`*`) tells that this should be done for every USB device connected.

That's it! Make sure that script is executable and plug your USB in!

ENjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With this, I created a script that copies all images automatically into a picture frame when it gets attached: https://github.com/AmmanVMS/picture-frame

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the tilde with the full path to your home directory. I don't know if this will work, but you say that the script works when you run it directly but when it's run automatically it doesn't: This makes me think that the problem might be to do with it being run by a different user when it's run automatically, and the tilde resolves to different values for different users.

Comment: Please read the comments before answering the question

Comment: I did read the comments, then I answered the question. Did I do something wrong? Which comment in particular are you referring to?

Comment: In comments these suggestions were already given and they didn't work for me..that is why I said read the comments

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, the last 5 comments were hidden from me and I didn't notice them. My mistake!

Comment: @Nullpointer: please edit your question and keep the complete information in the question so people don't need to read the comments...  Comments are not part of the question...  ;-)